# How to get HTTP body from TCP packet

Tags: java, http, tcp, packet-sniffers

I have below code ,I use pcap4j to sniff the packet and get the response . I convert the packet to TCP packet and try to get the rawData .I am able to get all the headers but with the HTTP response body shows garbage value .

Code :

```
 public void gotPacket(Packet packet) {
               TcpPacket tcpPacket = packet.get(TcpPacket.class);
  try {
          if(tcpPacket.getPayload()!=null) {
                        String hexStreamData = new String(tcpPacket.getPayload().getRawData(),"UTF-8");
                        System.out.println(hexStreamData);
             }
    } catch (Exception  e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

The output which I get is like below

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Xet-Cookie: dp1=bu1p/QEBfX0BAX19AQA**62f4c24b^;Domain=.abc.com;Expires=Thu, 11-Aug-2022 08:48:11 GMT;Path=/ 
Set-Cookie: s=CgAD4ACBfM6zLZDAxNjgasdvsfNzMwYTRlMdsfsdfgwZmZmZGI2YTZqfLYV;Domain=.abc.com;Path=/; HttpOnly 
Set-Cookie: nonsession=CgADLAAFfMmJTNxcafMJLMWNlZDQ0ZjUxNzMwYTRdsfsdYzMTc0Y2E0ZmZmZjNkM2Zyr0xe;Domain=.abc.com;Expires=Thu, 11-Aug-2022 08:48:11 GMT;Path=/ 
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 11 Aug 2020 08:48:10 GMT


11f
���Ok�0��"9����I�L�x�Mٱd鯵�&%y�Q���Vs��v�������p:�|)I��J����N7&5���#Q馜�X�)�  ��<o�x�LG
���xje���v����"�A�S�k�[��O��&�0x)S��O&&�c�7�o��)�ZE���D�e�Z��&��|����sT���h/�:������ZW�V�:���̬01�+��ߨo�WH{�Ft�1G�*�0O��s�z=�,;����N㍮���._�3��
0
```

As you see the I decode the HTTP headers correctly but I am still not able to get the body . I even tried to decode using Base 64 but it still doesn't give me desired result . I want to get the body of the HTTP response .

Comment: `Content-Encoding: gzip`

Comment: The body is compressed via `gzip`. See the `Content-Encoding: gzip` response header.

Comment: is it possible to get the payload from the TCP packet using pcap4j